# Process memory usage on Linux (post-mortem)

Tags: linux, memory, process

I'm trying to find memory usage stats for processes after they finish (on Linux).  Is there a way to do this?

I know I can get this data while a process is running by looking in /proc/{id}/status, but that file is gone after the process dies.

Comment: Why not doing it while the process is running?

Comment: Maybe he's trying to find out why it died.

Comment: I'm trying to include memory-usage in some benchmark data (from another program that starts these up), but I won't know the real peak usage till after the processes die.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this: http://tstarling.com/blog/2010/06/measuring-memory-usage-with-strace/

Answer (score 0):

[atop](http://www.atoptool.nl/) has a daemon mode, which will log various kinds of resource use by individual processes.

The debian package runs it as `/usr/bin/atop -a -w /var/log/atop.log 600`. You can access the data with `sudo atop -r`, and navigate to a time the system was loaded, or your application died, using `t` and `T`. There are various ways to present the data as well, similar to other top tools.